# How to check DB column is exists or not and after than add select Query

Tags: mysql

How to check DB column is exists or not and after than add select Query IF `EXISTS(t2.DateOfBill){t2.DateOfBill}else{t2.BillDate}` OR `IF EXISTS(t2.AreaId){t2.AreaId}`. I have mention below sample Query. Please Help.

```
Table
ID ShopID OrderID   
3  350    001414    
4  351    001415

Table2
ID TableID ShopId DateOfBill AreaID
1  3        350   2016/01/03  250

Table3
ID TableID ShopId BillDate 
1  4        351   2016/01/03




SELECT t1.id, t1.shopID,
IF EXISTS(t2.DateOfBill){t2.DateOfBill}else{t2.BillDate}, 
IF EXISTS(t2.AreaId){t2.AreaId} 
FROM TABLE t1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.OrderID = t1.OrderID AND t2.shopID = t1.shopID  
WHERE t1.OrderID IN ('001414') AND t1.shopID = 350 AND t1.Status = 'Open';


SELECT t1.id, t1.shopID,
IF EXISTS(t2.DateOfBill){t2.DateOfBill}else{t2.BillDate}, 
IF EXISTS(t2.AreaId){t2.AreaId} 
FROM TABLE t1 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 t2 ON t2.OrderID = t1.OrderID AND t2.shopID = t1.shopID  
WHERE t1.OrderID IN ('001414') AND t1.shopID = 350 AND t1.Status = 'Open';
```

I want manage all thing in single query.

Comment: What is the context in which you would be issuing queries for which certain columns might not even exist?  If you really need to do this, you might have to hit the information schema table first.

Comment: You cannot check within a select query whether a column exists or not, you must know that when you execute the query. You can only check if a column contains any value (null or not null) and if null, then use the value from another column (coalesce or ifnull). The latter case would be a duplicate question for sure.

Comment: I have update my question.